# c# - ping exceeds timeout but reports success

Tags: c#, networking, network-programming, ping

**Problem:**

in my code, I set a timeout of a ping to 100ms

```
new Ping().Send(item._deviceIP, 100, new byte[1])
```

which pings correctly and replies correctly, but the IPStatus.TimeExceeded is "faulty" and reports a success after the RTT is > 100ms

**What should happen:**

when recieving a pingreply, if the IPStatus is a:

- TimeExceeded (>100ms), _devicePing should have a color set to Red
- Success(<=100ms), _devicePing should have a color set to green
- any other, appropriate color is set.

**What happens:**

Any ping reply which is a reply report success even with a RTT >100ms

class device

```
{
    public IPAddress _deviceIP;
    public string _deviceMAC;
    public string _deviceName;
    public PingReply _devicePing ;
    public Color _deviceStatus = Color.White;
    public int _timeout_Count = 0;

    public Color deviceStatus
        {
            get { return _deviceStatus; }
            set { _deviceStatus = value; }
        }
```

Main Program Code

```
List<device> _alive = new List<device>();
foreach (device item in _clients)
{
    PingReply _client_reply = new Ping().Send(item._deviceIP, 100, new byte[1]);
    item._devicePing = _client_reply; (item object accepts a PingReply)
    IPStatus _client_status = _client_reply.Status;
    switch (_client_status)
    {
        case IPStatus.TimeExceeded:
        {
            item.deviceStatus = Color.Red;
        }        
        break;

    //rest of code
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check the status of the PingReply in all cases.
[When specifying very small numbers for timeout, the Ping reply can be received even if timeout milliseconds have elapsed.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144954%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

And now you ask the difficult question - what is a very small number 500ms, 250ms, 100ms 10ms, ??? Glad you asked .. see this article for no answwer to that question.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144954%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I know about this, but how does this solve my problem? Or rather, should I do my own TimeElapsed checking, since this is what it boils down to?

Comment: @KGCybeX - you will need to perform your own time elapsed checking. You can check in the pingreply if is > timeout = fail. I do not know any way to make the .NET library behave different than how it behaves - so you need to either work around it or roll your own. The work around is easier.